# Printing name of each layer in mxd using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, layers, mxd

My ArcMap verison is 10.2.

My goal is to print the name of each layer in a mxd using Arcpy.

My script is below. There is no error, but it prints the first layer multiple times instead of all the layers in the "Main Map" data frame.

Does anyone have a solution?

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"O:\Solar Databases\MO_projects.mxd")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Main Map")[0]
for lyr in df:
    x = 0
    name = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "", df)[x].name
    print name
    x = x+1
del mxd
```

Comment: You have two fundamental Python errors in this code. 1) You initialize `df` to the first element of a list, then try to iterate on the single element. 2) You reinitialize the `x` variable to zero with each iteration of the loop. Also, the canonical form of "increment x by one" is `x += 1`

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [ListLayers](https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s30000002n000000) to iterate the layers:

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"O:\Solar Databases\OSER Solar\Projects\(MO) Berntie Land Status.mxd")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Main Map")[0]
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, df): # List the layers in this data frame
    #x = 0 # if you set x=0 here then each iteration will start at 0 and finish at 1
    name = lyr.name
    print name
    #x = x+1 # the use of x is redundant
del mxd
```

Don't try to index the layer list directly, the order is arbitrary and not guaranteed to be in the same order in multiple calls. The direct indexing of [ListDataFrames](https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s30000002n000000) is acceptable *provided* there is only 1 data frame called "Main Map" - the order of 1 object, although arbitrary is still 1 object.

To work with layers *by index* you can do it this way:

```
import arcpy
mxd       = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"O:\Solar Databases\OSER Solar\Projects\(MO) Berntie Land Status.mxd")
df        = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Main Map")[0]
AllLayers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, df)

for x in range(len(AllLayers)):
    lyr  = AllLayers[x] # layer from list by index
    name = lyr.name
    print name
del mxd
```

Using the [range()](https://www.pythoncentral.io/pythons-range-function-explained/) function you create a list [0,1,2..n], where n is the number of items in the list minus 1 - remembering lists are 0 based (the first item is 0, the last is [len](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712227/how-to-get-the-number-of-elements-in-a-list-in-python)(list)-1). Get your list of layers **once** and then access it many times, that way you can guarantee the order hasn't changed during an iteration.

Comment: do you mean change name = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, df).name

Comment: You probably want to address the iteration of a singleton and  `x` reinitialization

Comment: With the edit x is redundant. ListLayers returns a list so  arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, df).name will return a type error, list has no attribute 'name'; the edit lists the layers *once* and then iterates the list in the variable lyr, which is a arcpy.mapping.Layer object which *does* have an attribute 'name'. Python has no for (int X = 0;X < Max;X++) loop so incrementing a counter and using an index on a list is not pythonic, to do this pythonically you would set AllLayers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, df) then for x in range(len(AllLayers)): and make lyr = AllLayers[x] - not relisting.